# Div style change on hover?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I've tried the following code to change some css properties (.overthumb) of a DIV (.thumbnail) when the mouse hovers over it. But, it doesn't work!!! Any tips would be good on how to get it working. If possible, for the changes to animate as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumbnail").hover(
        function(){
            $(".overthumb").show();
        },
        function(){
            $(".overthumb").hide();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I think this can be done with just CSS, could you post the HTML?

Comment: what means "it doesnt work" ? what result you want? overthumb is hidden on thumbnail hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do all this with CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/6wQp3/

---

Here's an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/6wQp3/5/).  I forgot to set the div to `position: relative;`.  Now the overlay should appear relative to the parent div.

Comment: How can I get this to work with more than one thumbnail on the same page? Without having to reproduce the same code but with a different class name for every thumbnail?

Comment: @Andy, see [the update](http://jsfiddle.net/6wQp3/5/).  I think it should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank You Sir, awesome help. I need to start working through the JQuery/Javascript book I bought!!

Answer (score 1):

`.hide` and `.show` will simply show and hide it.
You need the `.css` function to change the css.
More info here: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/XsJAK/

By the way, you could do all that with just CSS.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

Are you sure that your first element has a class called thumbnail and the second has a class called overthumb

Here is the working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/qBsya/

If you want to change some CSS properties, here is an example (This update the background color)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".thumbnail").hover(
    function(){
        $(".overthumb").css('background', '#C1A3A5').show();
    },
    function(){
        $(".overthumb").css('background', '#FFF').hide();
    }
);

});
```

working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/qBsya/4

Answer (score 1):

i would use the :hover facility of css, and then factor in a small amount of javascript for IE.

Answer (score 1):

The provided code looks correct, so there's probably something wrong elsewhere.

You can accomplish the same thing using css, and this is also recommended since it's cleaner. If you are not going to execute any other javascript methods on `:hover` this is the way to go.

```
.thumbnail:hover .overthumb {
  /* display:block; */
  display:inline;
}

.thumbnail .overthumb {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the advice. I've taken a bit of code that was doing something else and tried to adapt it. Unsuccessfully. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Did a simple animation too, check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XsJAK/1/), I have used jQuery’s `Animate()` Function

Comment: @Andy Check this out with other examples.